# which phtml file is called by $this->renderTotals()?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, totals, grand-total, render

In following path, `app\design\frontend\MYTHEME\default\template\checkout\cart\totals.phtml` file contains `$this->renderTotals().`

My question is that, which phtml file is called by `renderTotals()` method ?

I want to update Subtotal, Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed), Grand Total style in `http://localhost/MYTHEME/index.php/checkout/cart/`

Answer (score 8):

The easier way to find out what template is used is to enable the [template path hints](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints).
But here is the stacktrace you need to follow.

`Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals::renderTotals` calls `renderTotal` for each total.
This one calls `_getTotalRenderer` that works like this:

if there is a block with the name `$code_total_renderer` in the page ($code is the code of the total) then that block is used.
Most probably these blocks do not exist, but it's a good extension point because you can add any block you want.
If the block does not exist, it looks in the config for the node `global/sales/quote/totals/{$code}/renderer` and uses this one. The template should be defined in the block used.

you will find in `config.xml` of the Tax module (I have no idea why it's not in the sales module) this

```
     <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <tax_subtotal>
                    <class>tax/sales_total_quote_subtotal</class>
                    <after>freeshipping</after>
                    <before>tax,discount</before>
                </tax_subtotal>
                <tax_shipping>
                    <class>tax/sales_total_quote_shipping</class>
                    <after>shipping</after>
                    <before>tax,discount</before>
                </tax_shipping>
                <tax>
                    <class>tax/sales_total_quote_tax</class>
                    <after>subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                    <renderer>tax/checkout_tax</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>adminhtml/sales_order_create_totals_tax</admin_renderer>
                </tax>
                <subtotal>
                    <renderer>tax/checkout_subtotal</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>adminhtml/sales_order_create_totals_subtotal</admin_renderer>
                </subtotal>
                <shipping>
                    <renderer>tax/checkout_shipping</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>adminhtml/sales_order_create_totals_shipping</admin_renderer>
                </shipping>
                <discount>
                    <renderer>tax/checkout_discount</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>adminhtml/sales_order_create_totals_discount</admin_renderer>
                </discount>
                <grand_total>
                    <renderer>tax/checkout_grandtotal</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>adminhtml/sales_order_create_totals_grandtotal</admin_renderer>
                </grand_total>
            </totals>
            <nominal_totals>
                <nominal_tax_subtotal>
                    <class>tax/sales_total_quote_nominal_subtotal</class>
                    <sort_order>500</sort_order>
                </nominal_tax_subtotal>
                <nominal_tax>
                    <class>tax/sales_total_quote_nominal_tax</class>
                    <sort_order>750</sort_order>
                </nominal_tax>
            </nominal_totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
```

This means that for example for subtotal the block `tax/checkout_subtotal` is used. If you look inside the block you will see the template `tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml`.
You can take the same steps for all the other totals you need, but first give the template path hints a try. It may save you the trouble of digging through the xmls.